# A basic question on friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

Suppose A and B experience friction with each other but they move on a smooth floor. A is given a force F which is not enough to overcome friction; a frictional force equal to F, thus, acts on B. Now, one would expect both the objects to move together with a common acceleration, due to this friction. In which case, it can be said that

$\frac{F-f}{m_A}=\frac{f}{m_B}={a_A}={a_B}$

But this would imply that the accelerations of A and B are zero as $F=f$ for $F<{f_L}$. So does that mean that a force exerted on A that is less than the limiting value of static friction, will not result in collective acceleration of A and B?

This seems to contradict empirical behavior. For example, in case of a sufficiently heavy object on top of another, the application of a force that is not sufficient for the top object to overcome friction against the bottom object, still results in a collective acceleration.

I have attached a photo containing diagrams for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that the frictional force that acts on B, which is $f$, is equal to the force $F$ exerted on A. Since A exerts a force $f$ on B, then by Newton's 3rd Law, B exerts an equal and opposite force on A. If $f=F$ then the net force on A is zero and A will not accelerate. But we know that A does accelerate, so we must have $f < F$.

The net force on A is $F-f$, so the acceleration of A is $a_A = \frac {F-f} {m_a}$. Similarly, the net force on B is $f$ and the acceleration of B is $a_B = \frac f {m_B}$. If the blocks move together then they must have equal acceleration so

$a_A=a_B
\\ \Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac {F-f} {m_A} = \frac f {m_B}
\\ \Rightarrow (F-f)m_B = f m_A
\\ \Rightarrow \displaystyle F m_B = f(m_A + m_B)
\\ \Rightarrow \displaystyle a_A = a_B = \frac f {m_B} = \frac F {m_A + m_B}$

Comment: If the force applied is less than the limiting friction, then won't the friction basically act to stop the motion of A? I assumed that A "accelerates" only because it is affixed to B due to resistance from friction, while the reaction to that frictional force pulls B forward.

Comment: @SashankSriram A accelerates because the force $F$ is applied to it. B accelerates because the friction force $f$ acts so as to reduce relative motion between A and B. The reaction $-f$ to the friction force acts on A to reduce its acceleration. But if B moves faster than A then friction would act in the opposite direction, to accelerate A and decelerate B.

Comment: My question is, won't f basically *stop* the relative motion between A and B due to F, as F is lesser than the limiting value of static friction (refer diagram where I have specificed F < $f_L$)? Your explanation makes sense if the friction acting is kinetic, but in this case it is static. So it is going to increase with F until the limit, and any relative motion between A and B is only going to happen beyond this point.

Comment: @SashankSriram Yes, $f$ will stop any relative motion between A and B. And if there is no relative motion between A and B then they must have the same acceleration, which is $\frac F {m_A+m_B}$.

Comment: So if $f$ stops any relative motion between A and B, then $f$ would necessarily equal $F$ (which acts directly only on A). Then the equation you wrote above $\frac {F-f} {m_A} = \frac {f}{m_B}$ would imply that neither B nor A accelerates. Is that what you're implying?

Comment: @SashankSriram No, no, no. I think you are misunderstanding the term "relative motion". No relative motion between A and B just means that each is stationary *relative to the other*. They can - and they do - both still accelerate, as long as they both accelerate at the same rate. Since A *is* accelerating then $f$ is not equal to $F$.

Comment: Okay, on pondering a bit I realized that I had fundamentally misunderstood the meaning of static friction. So you're saying that static friction basically exists to prevent *relative motion* between two bodies and it need not necessarily be equal to the horizontal force applied, as in this particular case. Now, it all makes sense.